# Configure public_html and paths on cPanel when switching primary domains on hosting plan

Tags: hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting, file-manager

I have a hosting plan on my host provider (by **cPanel**). On that hosting package there is **one domain** which is a **primary domain or "carrier domain"** (**no other** addon domains or subdomains).

Then I bought a **new Domain** and I contatcted my hosting provider, that I wanted **to switch primary domains**, so the **new domain will be the primary domain**.

The primary domain is switched, but now I have to do **configurations in cPanel file manager**.

Now i have two questions?

**1. option:** I just bought both domains, on the first one I just tested Wordpress. So is there an option to delete the files on file manager and reinstal Wordpress on new domain. **If possible, I would like to have a fresh start in other words.**

**or**

**2. option:** I need to **configure files** by switching domain paths and web page in the public_html folder. **I dont know or Im not sure if I would find and switch everything. There should be some kind of instructions or in that case a tuturial**.

So both solutions would work for me. For the first option I searched, but could not found anything, but for the second option I am not quite sure how to change domain and web page and configure paths.

Thank you for your solutions.